# How do I get a path to a file?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to open a database.sqlite3. Firstly, I need to get a path.  But I don't know how to get this path.

I need a relative path.

[image]

***EDIT:*** I don't want to use NSBundle. It get a very long path.

I want to use /Users/Voloda2/Projects/facebook/database.sqlite3   Is it possible to get a relative path?

***EDIT2:*** I often change my database. I use Navicat for this operation. If I use NSBundle I have one problem. git did't indexed my database because it didn't lies in project folder. Thus I need to lay my database to project folder.

straight path is /Users/Voloda2/Projects/facebook/database.sqlite3

relative path something like this  ../database.sqlite3

Relative path is a path relative to project folder. 
Is it possible to get a relative path? May be it didn't possible.

Comment: This question is not as bad as to be downvoted. +1 to counter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're making a regular OS X/Cocoa app, Xcode will copy the database file to the app bundle. So, you can use the `NSBundle` class to obtain its path easily:

```
NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
```

Comment: H2CO3, please see my comment.

Comment: @Voloda2 what's the problem with the path being 'very long'? That's how applications are organized in OS X. Also, **to what** do you want to obtain a relative path? To the home directory? To the app's bundle directory?

Comment: @Voloda2 Why don't you just symlink the file in the project folder to the app bundle? (Btw you can define where your project is as a constant string, then use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`.)